# How can I get free space of a volume in a C program?

Tags: c, filesystems, volume

Just as the title says, how can I get a volume's free space inside a C program?
I am not using tricks like system(), they do not work well. (Why? Well, I already tried it!)

I need something like df, unfortunately I didn't find anything in the standard library.

Thank you very much.

Comment: for which OS? since this is OS specific.

Comment: the concept of "volume" belongs to a filesystem, not to memory allocations.

Comment: Working with Mac OSX, but i wish the code could be portable to linux too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a modern POSIX (Linux, OS X, etc.), you can use [statvfs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/statvfs.h.html):

```
struct statvfs st;
statvfs("/file/on/a/volume.ext", &st);
unsigned long free_space = st.f_bfree * st.f_frsize;
```

For Windows, WinAPI contains the [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Does not work, gives a huge value. I have 22GB free and it gives 5953005027328... Am I doing anything wrong?   Thank you very much

Comment: I'd use unsigned long free_space = st.f_bavail * st.f_bsize;

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! Solved! Thank you H2CO3!
Just one little thing: instead of st.f_bsize use st.frsize.
Now everything works! Thank you!

This is the working code:

```
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
struct statvfs st;
statvfs("/file/on/a/volume.ext", &st);
unsigned long free_space = st.f_bfree * st.f_frsize;
```